# Is creating linked service in data factory has been changed? There are not two options of connection string and keyvault anymore

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I created a **linked service in data factory using keyvault option** about some months ago. I wanted to create a new linked service some days ago and I understood the UI for linked service creation has been changed! 
Previously based on this article *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault#azure-key-vault-linked-service* there were two option **1. connection string (needed DB name, server name and username and password for DB)2.KeyVault(Just needed secret name and keyvault connection)**.
While now those two options has been changed to **1.password 2. Keyvault**. and the weird part is that in both two options DB name, username and password are mandatory! which is not acceptable because the point of using keyvault is not to share DB properties with developers and just sharing the secret name.
Does someone have any opinion about it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the json code of linked service to make it reference connection string.

[image]

Here's the format, then click finish button, it will be published.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It has been changed. Now you only need put your password into your azure Keyvault.
You old linked service will still work. But the new UI will only support password only azure Keyvault.